# adb push with no any printing

Tags: shell, batch-file, adb

i use the below code

```
adb push %DESKTOP_PATH%\Bill.txt %MOBILE_PATH%
```

and i receive

1663 KB/s (51182 bytes in 0.030s)

Is there any way not to show the above info??

Answer (score 3):

```
adb push %DESKTOP_PATH%\Bill.txt %MOBILE_PATH% 2>NUL >NUL
```

[Using command redirection operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)

Comment: You should redirect stdout before directing stderr to stdout (`>nul 2>&1`) or else direct both to nul in any order (`2>nul >nul`)

Answer (score 1):

Redirect your output to `nul`.

```
adb push %DESKTOP_PATH%\Bill.txt %MOBILE_PATH% > nul
```